# How to replace a range of values with NaN in Pandas data-frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge data-frame. How should I replace a range of values (-200, -100) with NaN?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried to do so far?  (The reason you're getting downvotes might be because you haven't discussed what you've done to solve the problem).

Comment: @ASGM I get that. I tried my best using multiple for loop but it was with many lines of code. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: If the code you've used to solve a problem is really long, it can still be useful to provide at least some of it along with a description of the approach you've taken, and the ways in which it has failed.  That gives potential answerers some context, as well as an indication that you've tried to solve it yourself first.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the question listed here. It's the reverse. The linked question asks how to drop NaNs, this asks how to add them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
In [145]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-250, 50, (10, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
     a    b    c
0 -188  -63 -228
1  -59  -70  -66
2 -110   39 -146
3  -67 -228 -232
4  -22 -180 -140
5 -191 -136 -188
6  -59  -30 -128
7 -201 -244 -195
8 -248  -30  -25
9   11    1   20

In [148]: df[(df>=-200) & (df<=-100)] = np.nan

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
       a      b      c
0    NaN  -63.0 -228.0
1  -59.0  -70.0  -66.0
2    NaN   39.0    NaN
3  -67.0 -228.0 -232.0
4  -22.0    NaN    NaN
5    NaN    NaN    NaN
6  -59.0  -30.0    NaN
7 -201.0 -244.0    NaN
8 -248.0  -30.0  -25.0
9   11.0    1.0   20.0
```

Comment: Use the following to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning` message: `df.loc[:, (df>=-200) & (df<=-100)] = np.nan`

Comment: The code throws an error: `None of [Index([('a',), ('b',), ('c',)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]` - do you have an idea about the reason (maybe an update) and a solution? :) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Ivo, thank you for pointing it out - the old solution used to work properly under old Pandas version. It's fixed now - please test...

Answer (score 18):

#### dataframe

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.mask((df >= -200) & (df <= -100), inplace=True)
```

This method replaces elements identified by `True` values in a Boolean array with a specified value, defaulting to `NaN` if a value is not specified.

Equivalently, use [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with the reverse condition:

```
df.where((df < -200) | (df > -100), inplace=True)
```

#### series

As with many methods, Pandas helpfully includes versions which work with series rather than an entire dataframe. So, for a column `df['A']`, you can use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['A'].mask(df['A'].between(-200, -100), inplace=True)
```

For chaining, note `inplace=False` by default, so you can also use:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['A'].between(-200, -100))
```